# JVM is using too much memory in server

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I have a web application which logs data from various portals.
This is a java application which uses mongo db as DB server.
My application is fast enough but issue i am facing is Tomcat is eating up too much Ram memory on each application server. I have to restart tomcat in every two hours to free up this memory otherwise it becomes non- responsive. I run netstat -n | wc -l on each server and average out put is 1000 on each server.
I introduced System.gc in my servlet and mongo dao to force GC to free up memory but it increased the CPU uses to 100%.
Could you please suggest any way how this memory issue will be resolved.

Comment: Create the dump at particular time and analyse it.

Comment: I created the heap dump at interval of 30 minutes but there was not definite pattern of some objects in increasing order always. I found that there are lot of string objects created.

Comment: Do you see proof that memory usage is near full and GC kicks in? In the meantime, "netstat -n | wc -l" getting back 1000 sounds like a lot. On my machine, I got back 100 or so. Could it be that the connections are not closed properly?

Comment: this 1000 has connections established,waiting. I checked my db connections also and in my code i am closing it correctly (I think so) I start my db connection always with db.requestStart() and in finally i call db.requestDone().

Answer (score 0):

I use following approach to finding memory leaks in Java. I've used jProfiler with great success, but I believe that any specialized tool with graphing capabilities (diffs are easier to analyze in graphical form) will work.

Start the application and wait until it get to "stable" state, when all the initialization is complete and the application is idle.
Run the operation suspected of producing a memory leak several times to allow any cache, DB-related initialization to take place.
Run GC and take memory snapshot.
Run the operation again. Depending on the complexity of operation and sizes of data that is processed operation may need to be run several to many times.
Run GC and take memory snapshot.
Run a diff for 2 snapshots and analyze it.
Basically analysis should start from greatest positive diff by, say, object types and find what causes those extra objects to stick in memory.

For web applications that process requests in several threads analysis gets more complicated, but nevertheless general approach still applies.

I did quite a number of projects specifically aimed at reducing memory footprint of the applications and this general approach with some application specific tweaks and trick always worked well.